# .left-column[] and .right-column][] do not align

Tags: css, r, xaringan

I am not sure if it is on purpose but as you can see below the left column and the right column do not align. I played around with my browsers devtools and found a top padding for the right column. But even after removing this it does not align perfectly. Is there some easy way to achieve perfect alignment?

```
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---


## Header
.left-column[Left Column]
.right-column[Right Column]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that .right-column has a 1 em top padding. You may customize the css within the Rmarkdown file by adding the following at the beginning.

````
```{css echo=FALSE}
.right-column{
  padding-top: 0;
}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are some special CSS classes that come with `xaringan` which take care of this issue.

```
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---


## Header
.left-column[`.left-column`]
.right-column[`.right-column`]

.pull-left[`.pull-left`]
.pull-right[`.pull-right`]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I actually want to use `.left-column` and `.right-column` because of the proportions. I solved it by rewriting the css classes.